# FAIL - Application at context path [/OpenClinica] could not be started

Tags: jdbc, tomcat9

I am trying to understand why my application is not starting. I have deployed the war file using tomcat manager, but the application is not starting. I followed the installation process so I would have the correct Java version for Tomcat9. Here is what my log is saying. But I am not understanding. Any help appreciated.

From the catalina.log

```
> 27-Jul-2023 13:25:36.081 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-24]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
> application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software
> Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\OpenClinica.war] has finished in
> [113,068] ms 27-Jul-2023 13:28:08.338 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
> scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
> logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
> found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
> startup time and JSP compilation time. 27-Jul-2023 13:28:44.214 INFO
> [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate.comment Lock Database
> 27-Jul-2023 13:28:44.265 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> liquibase.lock.LockHandler.acquireLock Successfully acquired change
> log lock 27-Jul-2023 13:28:49.458 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.getRanChangeSetList Reading from
> databasechangelog 27-Jul-2023 13:28:51.578 INFO
> [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate.comment Changeset
> migration/amethyst/2011-05-28-9305.xml::2011-05-9305-1::ahamid::(MD5Sum:
> 43702d44b436cbc7f56f6bd81c8ff116) 27-Jul-2023 13:28:51.657 INFO
> [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> liquibase.database.template.JdbcTemplate.comment Release Database Lock
> 27-Jul-2023 13:28:51.662 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> liquibase.lock.LockHandler.releaseLock Successfully released change
> log lock 27-Jul-2023 13:28:51.799 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
> listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
> appropriate container log file 27-Jul-2023 13:28:51.802 SEVERE
> [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context
> [/OpenClinica] startup failed due to previous errors 27-Jul-2023
> 13:28:51.932 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc
> The web application [OpenClinica] registered the JDBC driver
> [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web
> application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has
> been forcibly unregistered. 27-Jul-2023 13:28:51.934 WARNING
> [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
> The web application [OpenClinica] appears to have started a thread
> named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@36c35ac1] but has failed to stop
> it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of
> thread:  java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
> java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552) 
> java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) 27-Jul-2023 13:28:51.936
> WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-31]
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
> The web application [OpenClinica] appears to have started a thread
> named [Timer-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to
> create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
> java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
> java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552) 
> java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) 27-Jul-2023 13:30:18.526
> INFO [Timer-3]
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading
> Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
> already. Could not load
> [org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList$Cursor]. The
> following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to
> attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application
> instance has been stopped already. Could not load
> [org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList$Cursor]. The
> following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to
> attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.      at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1432)
>       at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
>       at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1259)
>       at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
>       at
> org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList.cursor(CursorableLinkedList.java:305)
>       at
> org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.evict(GenericObjectPool.java:1488)
>       at
> org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1700)
>       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)       at
> java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) 27-Jul-2023 13:33:29.256
> INFO [Timer-4]
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading
> Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
> already. Could not load
> [org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList$Cursor]. The
> following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to
> attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application
> instance has been stopped already. Could not load
> [org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList$Cursor]. The
> following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to
> attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.      at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1432)
>       at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
>       at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1259)
>       at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
>       at
> org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList.cursor(CursorableLinkedList.java:305)
>       at
> org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.evict(GenericObjectPool.java:1488)
>       at
> org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1700)
>       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)       at
> java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

From tomcat9_stout log:

```
> 13:28:10,020 |-ERROR in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender[SYSLOG-USAGESTATS] - Could
> not create SyslogWriter java.net.UnknownHostException:
> usage.openclinica.com     at java.net.UnknownHostException:
> usage.openclinica.com     at  at
> java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)    at  at
> java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:867)    at  at
> java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
>   at  at
> java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:815)
>   at  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1291)    at
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1144)     at  at
> java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1065)  at  at
> java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1015)     at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.net.SyslogOutputStream.<init>(SyslogOutputStream.java:44)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender.createOutputStream(SyslogAppender.java:61)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.net.SyslogAppenderBase.start(SyslogAppenderBase.java:54)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender.start(SyslogAppender.java:51)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:96)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:317)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:196)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:182)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
>   at  at
> ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
>   at  at
> org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)    at
>   at
> org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
>   at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:129)     at  at
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
>   at  at
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)     at
>   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)    at  at
> org.akaza.openclinica.dao.core.OCContextLoaderListener.<init>(OCContextLoaderListener.java:15)
>   at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at  at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at  at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4421)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1438)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:702)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:220)
>   at  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
>   at  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:190)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
>   at  at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:596)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:355)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:54)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   at  at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   at  at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
>   at  at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
>   at  at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
>   at  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
>   at  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
>   at  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
>   at  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
>   at  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) 13:28:10,025 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity
> of logger [org.hibernate.SQL] to false 13:28:10,025 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate.SQL
> level set to ERROR 13:28:10,892 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [DB_LOGFILE] to Logger[org.hibernate.SQL] 13:28:10,904
> |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting
> additivity of logger [org.hibernate.type] to false 13:28:10,904 |-INFO
> in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction -
> org.hibernate.type level set to ERROR 13:28:10,915 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [DB_LOGFILE] to Logger[org.hibernate.type] 13:28:10,927
> |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting
> additivity of logger [org.hibernate] to false 13:28:10,927 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate level
> set to ERROR 13:28:10,942 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity
> of logger [org.springframework.security] to false 13:28:10,942 |-INFO
> in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction -
> org.springframework.security level set to ERROR 13:28:10,953 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-AUTHPRIV] to
> Logger[org.springframework.security] 13:28:10,963 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity
> of logger [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3] to false 13:28:10,963
> |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction -
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3 level set to ERROR 13:28:10,974
> |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction -
> Attaching appender named [DB_LOGFILE] to
> Logger[org.springframework.orm.hibernate3] 13:28:10,984 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity
> of logger [org.springframework.core.io] to false 13:28:10,984 |-INFO
> in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction -
> org.springframework.core.io level set to ERROR 13:28:10,991 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-OTHER] to Logger[org.springframework.core.io]
> 13:28:10,997 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity
> of logger [org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent] to false
> 13:28:10,998 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction
> - org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent level set to INFO 13:28:11,004 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [WS_LOGFILE] to
> Logger[org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent] 13:28:11,014
> |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting
> additivity of logger
> [org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received] to false
> 13:28:11,014 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction
> - org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received level set to INFO 13:28:11,023 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [WS_LOGFILE] to
> Logger[org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received]
> 13:28:11,030 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction
> - liquibase level set to INFO 13:28:11,036 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [DB_LOGFILE] to Logger[liquibase] 13:28:11,043 |-INFO
> in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting
> additivity of logger [org.akaza.openclinica] to false 13:28:11,043
> |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction -
> org.akaza.openclinica level set to INFO 13:28:11,055 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-OTHER] to Logger[org.akaza.openclinica]
> 13:28:11,055 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-LPR] to Logger[org.akaza.openclinica]
> 13:28:11,055 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-USER] to Logger[org.akaza.openclinica]
> 13:28:11,056 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-MAIL] to Logger[org.akaza.openclinica]
> 13:28:11,056 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-AUTH] to Logger[org.akaza.openclinica]
> 13:28:11,056 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-UUCP] to Logger[org.akaza.openclinica]
> 13:28:11,056 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-AUTHPRIV] to Logger[org.akaza.openclinica]
> 13:28:11,065 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity
> of logger [org.akaza.openclinica.exception] to false 13:28:11,065
> |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction -
> org.akaza.openclinica.exception level set to INFO 13:28:11,070 |-INFO
> in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [LOGFILE-DAEMON] to
> Logger[org.akaza.openclinica.exception] 13:28:11,080 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity
> of logger
> [org.akaza.openclinica.service.usageStats.LogUsageStatsService] to
> false 13:28:11,081 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction -
> org.akaza.openclinica.service.usageStats.LogUsageStatsService level
> set to INFO 13:28:11,086 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [SYSLOG-USAGESTATS] to
> Logger[org.akaza.openclinica.service.usageStats.LogUsageStatsService]
> 13:28:11,086 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity
> of logger [jdbc.sqltiming] to false 13:28:11,086 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - jdbc.sqltiming level
> set to INFO 13:28:11,086 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
> appender named [DB_LOGFILE] to Logger[jdbc.sqltiming] 13:28:11,086
> |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction -
> End of configuration. 13:28:11,092 |-INFO in
> ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@2fb0f4cb - Registering
> current configuration as safe fallback point
> 
>  > orderByFragment(order-by)
>   > sortSpecification({sort specification})
>    > sortKeySpecification(sort key)
>     > sortKey($PlaceHolder$.ordinal)
>     < sortKey(null)    < sortKeySpecification(asc)
>    > orderingSpecification(asc)    < orderingSpecification(null)   < sortSpecification(null)  < orderByFragment(null)
>  > orderByFragment(order-by)
>   > sortSpecification({sort specification})
>    > sortKeySpecification(sort key)
>     > sortKey($PlaceHolder$.discrepancy_note_id)
>     < sortKey(null)    < sortKeySpecification(asc)
>    > orderingSpecification(asc)    < orderingSpecification(null)   < sortSpecification(null)  < orderByFragment(null)
>  > orderByFragment(order-by)
>   > sortSpecification({sort specification})
>    > sortKeySpecification(sort key)
>     > sortKey($PlaceHolder$.discrepancy_note_id)
>     < sortKey(null)    < sortKeySpecification(asc)
>    > orderingSpecification(asc)    < orderingSpecification(null)   < sortSpecification(null)  < orderByFragment(null)
>  > orderByFragment(order-by)
>   > sortSpecification({sort specification})
>    > sortKeySpecification(sort key)
>     > sortKey($PlaceHolder$.discrepancy_note_id)
>     < sortKey(null)    < sortKeySpecification(asc)
>    > orderingSpecification(asc)    < orderingSpecification(null)   < sortSpecification(null)  < orderByFragment(null)
>  > orderByFragment(order-by)
>   > sortSpecification({sort specification})
>    > sortKeySpecification(sort key)
>     > sortKey($PlaceHolder$.discrepancy_note_id)
>     < sortKey(null)    < sortKeySpecification(asc)
>    > orderingSpecification(asc)    < orderingSpecification(null)   < sortSpecification(null)  < orderByFragment(null)
>  > orderByFragment(order-by)
>   > sortSpecification({sort specification})
>    > sortKeySpecification(sort key)
>     > sortKey($PlaceHolder$.date_updated)
>     < sortKey(null)    < sortKeySpecification(asc)
>    > orderingSpecification(asc)    < orderingSpecification(null)   < sortSpecification(null)  < orderByFragment(null)
>  > orderByFragment(order-by)
>   > sortSpecification({sort specification})
>    > sortKeySpecification(sort key)
>     > sortKey($PlaceHolder$.discrepancy_note_id)
>     < sortKey(null)    < sortKeySpecification(asc)
>    > orderingSpecification(asc)    < orderingSpecification(null)   < sortSpecification(null)  < orderByFragment(null)
>  > orderByFragment(order-by)
>   > sortSpecification({sort specification})
>    > sortKeySpecification(sort key)
>     > sortKey($PlaceHolder$.discrepancy_note_id)
>     < sortKey(null)    < sortKeySpecification(asc)
>    > orderingSpecification(asc)    < orderingSpecification(null)   < sortSpecification(null)  < orderByFragment(null) Error getting
> jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/openclinica view with select
> definition from pg_views where viewname='_pg_foreign_data_wrappers'
> AND schemaname='public'
```

Comment: _"Could not create SyslogWriter java.net.UnknownHostException:"_ it seems you have a configuration error which prevents your application from starting.